# Этимология слова "кузнец"

Tags: этимология

Вот интересно, каково происхождение слова "кузнец", "кузница"? По-украински будет "коваль" - тут сразу понятно, что от слова "ковать". А по-русски?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле **ковать, коваль, кузня, кузнец** - однокоренные слова. Др.-рус. *ковати* восходит к праслав. *kovati, который образован с суф. -a-ti от* коvъ < 
и.-е. *k**ou**-/*keu- < *sk- <* ks-, *kes- «бить, рубить, резать, ковать». На слав. почве древн. дифтонг **оu** перед гласн. развился в сочетание -**ов**-, а перед согласн. дал -**у**-, отсюда чередов. в корне **ов/у**. См.* ковать *(<* ковати, кую*) и производные от него устар.* ковач *«кузнец», укр.* коваль *(сюда же относится* коварный*). Глаг.* кути *(«ковать») послужил производящей основой для сущ.* кузнь*. К основе **ку**- присоединен суф. -**знь**, который указывал на состояние (как в слове* жизнь*). Следоват., сущ.* кузнь *первонач. значило «ковка», а затем «изделие ковки» (ср. в XIV в.* 
кузнь *«все кованое»). С преобразованием* кузнь *в **кузня** (по типу* песнь — 
песня*) у слова* кузня *по аналогии с сущ.* поварня *развилось знач. «место 
изготовления кованых изделий». Сущ. **кузнь** в знач. «ковка» дало сущ.* кузньць > кузнец* «мастер по ковке металла» с суф. деятеля -ъц-ъ-> -ц- с суф. -иц-а — сущ. **кузница** «место, где куют». От сущ. **кузнец** уменьш. с суф. -ик- **кузнечик**, которое использовано для названия насекомого, издающего стрекочущие (кующие) звуки.