# Как кузнечик связан с кузнецом?

Tags: этимология, лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, история

Известно, что слово «кузнечик» является суффиксальным производным от «кузнец». Но как эти два слова связаны по смыслу? В чем причина того, что насекомое стало называться именно так, а не иначе?

Comment: Одна из версий есть и у нас на сайте:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/Этимология-слова-кузнец

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова спасибо. Я видел, но там не совсем эта тема и пояснение краткое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Видимо, связаны звуковыми ассоциациями. Стрекотание сверчков отличается монотонностью, чем-то напоминает металлическое, как будто кто-то постукивает молоточком, трудится. Так называемые "смычок" и "скрипка" (своеобразные перепонки) насекомых "играют" отчётливо и звонко. Кузнец в кузнице, работая молотом, тоже издаёт монотонные звуки, слышные по всей  округе.

Русское слово «кузнечик» впервые фиксируется в письменном виде в дополнениях к «Актам историческим» за 1674 год: «... да добыть полевых кузнечиков зеленых, которые по травкам скачют... » - и это уменьшительное от «кузнец» . До этого был «изок» ". Месяц июнь в языческие времена назывался "изок". В древнерусском языке слово "изок" означает "кузнечик". Это месяц стрёкота насекомых и вечного праздника с трескотнёй крыльев стрекоз и шелестом зелёной травы.

ИЗОК в  Этимологическом русскоязычном словаре Фасмера:

"кузнечик, цикада", также "июнь", русск. -цслав. изокъ (ср. др. -русск. чьрвьць "соссus" и "июнь"), первонач. "пучеглазое (насекомое) ". От из- и око.

Так что раньше заостряли внимание на пучеглазости - изок, в диалектах его называли кобылкой, так как он скакал как кобылка, чаще было общее слово цикады - тоже звук.

Comment: Я думал об этом; все-таки не слишком убедительно, ведь есть и другие процессы, при которых издаваемые звуки также монотонны: чем капание воды, рубка дровосеком деревьев и т. д. хуже ударов молота кузнеца? Конечно, нельзя сводить вопрос лишь к "почему кузнец, а не дровосек", но и нельзя считать только звуковое сходство достаточным объяснением.

Comment: В  других языках оно чаще всего связано с манерой насекомого высоко и далеко прыгать: «скакалец» (болг.), «коник-стрибунець» (укр.), «конік» (белор.), «skakavac» (босн.).В России во времена Пушкина и Крылова его называли стрекозой (в басне"Стрекоза и муравей" речь идёт не о современной стрекозе, а о кузнечике) Все областнические названия кузнечика были привязаны либо к звуку, либо к прыганью ( стрекозы, цикады, коники, кобылки) . 
Где-то же связали звук кузнечика с маленькими невидимыми кузнецами. В результате это название почти вытеснило остальные.

Answer (score 1):

В фундаментальном "Этимологическом словаре славянских языков" под редакцией О.Н.Трубачёва в статье "кузнец" говорится, что во многих областях диалектное "кузнец" само по себе означало "кузнечик" (более прямой связи между этими словами в словаре нет). А в других областях были ещё и такие значения: 'стрекоза' (брян.), 'птица синица' (олон.), 'птица козодой' (сиб.). Хочу отметить, что в той же статье говорится, что в древнерусском и церковнославянском языках слово "кузнец" означало ещё 'колдун, чародей; странствующий актер'. Вот это последнее значение (с учётом красивых/громких насекомых и птиц) привлекло моё внимание.

На этом хорошие новости заканчиваются. В словаре не делают никакого вывода о связи слов "кузнец" и "странстввющий актёр". О прямой же связи корней слова "кузнец" со словами "колдун, колдовство" говорится неоднократно.

Посмотрел ещё несколько историко-этимологических словарей, но безрезультатно. Хотел дополнить ответ ещё какой-то информацией о "кузнечике" из словаря Трубачёва, но Людмила меня опередила. Несмотря на отрицательный результат поисков, я решил написать в ответе об этом небольшом исследовании :)

Comment: Спасибо! Думаю, что представление о кузнечике как о живущем в траве кудеснике маловероятно )

Comment: @Aer Я не предлагал вариант с колдуном :) А насчёт "странствующего актёра" я не уверен. Есть ли основания рассматривать эту версию либо, наоборот, уверенно отказаться от неё? Жаль, что в словаре ничего об этом не сказано.

Comment: версия сомнительна, по-моему; хотя в фольклоре, наверно, есть похожие представления (кажется, они поздние). Звуковая связь убедительней.

Comment: @Aer Да, согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Мне тоже стало интересно, почему кузнечика так назвали.
А ведь кузнец работал не только молотом, он ещё точил мечи.
Думаю тут ассоциация такая - кузнец точит меч, как и кузнечик "точит" ногами.
И у самок кузнечика яйцеклад напоминает меч.