# причины конвергенции(?!) созвучия кухня и кузня?

Tags: этимология, фольклор

Cудя по википедии кухня - пришло с немецкого  тогда как кузня в более древней форме было уже и во славянском

при этом дистанция в один символ теперь ( не настолько различно кит-кот)

это конвергенция исходна совсем разных гнёзд или в том же индоевропейском(али где по дереву языков-диалектов-наречий-говоров-...) есть общее гнездо  общее понятие для помещения по готовке "продукта"?

Comment: Вот пример куда более удивительной "конвергенции": пассировка → массировка → маскировка → маркировка → маршировка → фаршировка. Если проследить связь всех явлений и языков, участвующих в этимологии и "конвергенции" этих терминов, можно было бы замахнуться на диссертацию.

Answer (score 2):

Совпадение последних букв в словах "кухня" и "кузня" не может служить доказательством их родства. В нашем (и не только) языке названия помещений частенько оканчиваются на «ня», например: пекарня, печатня, бочарня, пивоварня, изба-читальня. Это касается не только производственных помещений, но и бытовых (спальня, баня, харчевня), и «стойловых» (конюшня, псарня).
Корень слова "кухня" связывают с «kok < лат. coquus — тж., того же корня, что печь и пекарь».

Ку́хня. Заимств. в XVI в. из польск. яз., где kuchnia < др.-в.-нем. kuchina, передающего лат. coquina «кухня, кулинарное искусство», суф. производного от coquere «варить» (см. кок).
Происхождение слова кухня в этимологическом онлайн-словаре Шанского Н. М.

Корень слова "кузня" никак не связан с "выпечкой / кексами". Его сближают со словом "ковать". Об этом уже говорилось здесь:
[Этимология слова "кузнец"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4802/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86)